# Solve $y’’ + 2y’ +y = xe^{-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So my questions is to solve: $y’’ + 2y’ +y = xe^{-x}$

The general solution is: $(Ax + B)e^{-x} = Axe^{-x} + Be^{-x}$.

To Find the particular solution we could assume a solution of the form $y_p = Axe^{-x}$ but we see that this solution would be covered by the general solution.

Instead we try to use $Ax^2e^{-x}$. **What is the intuition behind multiplying with $x$?** Why not add a polynomial, a sine or something else?

Solving for $A$ gives me $\frac{1}{2}x^2e^{-x}$. WolframAlpha suggests $\frac{1}{6}x^3e^{-x}$ as the correct answer.

Should I have looked for a solution of the form $Ax^3e^{-x}$ and multiplied $Axe^{-x} \times x^2$? **What would be the intuition / reason for that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we speak about *intuition*, whenever I see a differential equation like the one you posted, my first reaction is to set $y=e^{-x}\,u$. This makes $$u''=x$$ Then, it is clear that an $x^3$ will be coming.

Is this OK for you ?

Suppose now that we face $$y’’ + 2y’ +y = P_n(x) \,e^{-x}$$ where $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, the same procedure would lead to $$u''=P_n(x)$$ and then the solution has to be a polynomial of degree $(n+2)$.

Comment: Thanks! Will think this through but it looks reasonable! Would you say that you would use the same approach for diffrential equations like this:
$y'' + 2y' + y = P_n (x)$?

Comment: @LukasArvidsson. Yes, for sure. Just two successive integrations to get $u$ and then $y$. By the way, you are very welcome !

Comment: Other than nasty algebra is there any reason why we couldnt use variation of constants?